# special characters in php

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I want to display some chemistry equations like <sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K ([source](http://scitechdaily.com/mit-physicists-create-ultracold-molecules-of-23na40k/)).

This value is in my database. Now it's display like this `$^{23}$Na$^{40}$K`.  I tried to use `html_entity_decode()`, `utf8_decode()`, `stripslashes()`. Nothing works for me. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: changed tags, this is not php or display related, but html

Comment: Do you mean this part? 23Na40K? `<sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K`

Comment: @st2erw2od undelete your answer now! or you risk losing 15 up-votes fast :)

Comment: I've assumed you referred to the equation in title and edited the question accordingly. Otherwise you'll need to clarify: a link to a chemistry article is not a good programming question.

Comment: Why do you want special characters? It's only html: http://prntscr.com/atn5kp

Comment: @Álvaro González, I tried to display the above equation in PHP. URL provided in my question is just a reference, that dosen't mean it's chemistry related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K**

```
<sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K
```

And

**H<sub>2</sub>O**

```
H<sub>2</sub>O
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `Superscript` in **HTML** like this:

Output: <sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K

```html
<sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Equation HTML generator](http://www.periodni.com/chemical_equations_on_web.php) and use it into your website.

Or, you can also use [Latex](https://www.mathjax.org/) for displaying full equation html.

Answer (score 0):

I havent seen anyone mention these:
`¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰`

Which are some Unicode Characters which don't look as good as the Superscript Tags but, if you still want to use HTML entities here they are:
`&sup1;&sup2;&sup3;&#8308;&#8309;&#8310;&#8311;&#8312;&#8313;&#8304;`

Heres a comparison

```html
HTML Tags: <sup>23</sup>Na<sup>40</sup>K
<br>Or<br>
HTML Entities: &sup2;&sup3;Na&#8308;&#8304;K
```